# org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeException: No barcode configuration element not found

Tags: java, svg, barcode4j

I want to generate a barcode in svg from a barcode xml.
I have followed this: http://barcode4j.sourceforge.net/2.1/barcode-xml.html

The input should be a configuration object created out of an xml file.
The "cfgFile"[barcode.xml] file is of the following format:

```
<bc:barcode xmlns:bc="http://barcode4j.krysalis.org/ns" orientation="0" message="123456789">
    <bc:code39>
            <bc:height>15mm</bc:height>
            <bc:module-width>0.19mm</bc:module-width>
            <bc:wide-factor>2.5</bc:wide-factor>
    </bc:code39>
</bc:barcode>
```

When I try to send this as input to Barcode 4j:

```
DefaultConfigurationBuilder builder = new 
DefaultConfigurationBuilder();
File cfgFile = new File("barcode.xml");
Configuration cfgnew = builder.buildFromFile(cfgFile);
DocumentFragment frag = 
BarcodeUtil.getInstance().generateSVGBarcode(cfgnew, "123456789");
```

I get the following error:

```
Caused by: org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeException: No barcode configuration element not found
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeUtil.createBarcodeGenerator(Unknown Source) ~[Barcode4J-2.1.jar:?]
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeUtil.createBarcodeGenerator(Unknown Source) ~[Barcode4J-2.1.jar:?]
at org.krysalis.barcode4j.BarcodeUtil.generateSVGBarcode(Unknown Source) ~[Barcode4J-2.1.jar:?
```

When I print a logger for cfgnew,
I get this: 
bc:barcode:::@file

Comment: How do you affect value to `cfgFile` in your Java code ? Is the XML you provided strictly equal to the XML you are actually using ?

Comment: yes, The XML provided above is the one that the cfgFile contains.

Comment: As far as I can see, your XML is not valid. that might be related. BTW, you still have not given the code that affects the variable cfgFile.

Comment: Edited the line where it creates the file "barcode.xml" and is sent as "cfgFile"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the wrong function to generate the barcode in SVG.
Instead of 
    BarcodeUtil.getInstance().generateSVGBarcode(cfgnew, "123456789");

Use this:
    bargen.generateBarcode(canvas, msg);

where bargen is the instance for a particular barcode configuration.